# SSIS Flat File Destination Setting Connection String to variable + string

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using SSDT 2016 and Sql Server 2014.

I am outputting a bunch of Flat Files with debug information during my import.  For these I use Flat File Connection Managers.  I have a project variable DebugOutputFolder.

I can't figure out how to set the Flat File Connection String to:
@[Package::DebugOutputFolder] + "file1.csv".

Does anyone know how to specify that?

Answer (score 0):

Find the Connection String property of the Flat File's connection manager, and click the ellipsis (...) button and create an expression.

Comment: This isn't exactly how it worked but it was close.  You have to parameterize the connection string and then modify it in the Flat File Destination->Properties->Expressions